# Ajax call/response too long

Tags: php, jquery

First sorry for my bad english, i'm a new user but i read long ago this site and help me many problem resolve. Thanks all for this. Now unfortunately i dont find resolve for my problem.

I dont know why 2000 ms my all ajax call. All at same what thing the called .php file.
I try a lot of technique to resolve this but not help.

**The task is refresh many div content in "real time" with database syncronization.**
The site contains some timer. When the timer text equal 00:00:00 i call the update script.

my ajax call:

```
$(function() {
function update()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/update.php",
        async: true,
                    success: function() {
          update();
                    }
            });
}
update();
    });
```

my update php:

```
    include 'inc/config.php';
    include 'inc/conn/connopn.php';
    $sDataForSync = "";
    $iRowsNum = 0;
    $sGetDataQuery = mysql_query("select `AID`, `PN` FROM `my_table1`;");
if (mysql_num_rows($sGetDataQuery ) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sGetDataQuery )) {
        $iRowsNum++;
        if ($iRowsNum == mysql_num_rows($sGetDataQuery )) {
            $sDataForSync .= $row['AID'] . "|" . $row['PN'];
        } else {
            $sDataForSync .= $row['AID'] . "|" . $row['PN'] . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
        file_put_contents("updates.txt",$sDataForSync );
/* for now only write to text file, but later i would like to update in database */
include 'inc/conn/conncls.php';
```

The table contains max 30-40 rows and i using indexes, but still 2 seconds the response.
I need 200-400 ms, max 500ms responsetime with prospective mysql update query.

[firefox results](http://www.kephost.com/view3.php?filename=a1_2014_3_20_mhwby758z1.png)

Please help me decreases the time.
Thanks for all!

Comment: You cannot guarantee a fast response time (200-400 ms) from a Web Service as that depends on the client location and server & network speeds. How long does a page take to come up from that server? Probably 2 seconds I would guess :)

Comment: On localhost also?
i not beleve depends the network speed on localhost
or does it?

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the request using something like Fiddler2 (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Among other things it will show the response timing. Your server must be running the request too slowly.

Comment: In another site, with same net, pc, etc the same function is 400 ms.
How? :P

Fiddler results: http://www.kephost.com/view3.php?filename=a1_2014_3_20_mp7r1pz8m9.png

Comment: Your MySql, or web server, must be running very slowly. Return a fixed response, instead of database query, and check local timing to see which is the slow one.

Comment: As i think the webserver, but i dont know how to check what is slow inside that.

this mysql query result (run from phpmyadmin):
 Sorok megjelenítése 0- 7 (összesen 8, a lekérdezés 0.0006 másodpercig tartott)

total 8 row
0.0006 seconds

Comment: I tested the code on hosting(http://domain-tarhely.net) also. The time same with my localhost. ~2000 ms.

Comment: I try this call with another php file.
the php file 2 row
$x=file_get_contents("x.txt");
file_put_contents("y.txt",$x);
this .txt file is 20 rows and 472 byte

this task is 1 second. I don't understand why?!

Comment: SOLVED.
1 sec is my fail. I left the second parameter from mysql_query.
mysql_query("select",$dbconn);
The another second is my web server fail. Too slowly. The mysql_connect(); is 1 second in localhost but on the remote server
the full operation is 50-80 ms.
Thanks for all the posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. 1 sec is my fail. I left the second parameter from mysql_query. mysql_query("select",$dbconn); The another second is my web server fail. Too slowly. The mysql_connect(); is 1 second in localhost but on the remote server the full operation is 50-80 ms. Thanks for all the posts.